# Android: Strange error while setting an TextView.setText(..);

Tags: android, widget

public class Game extends Activity
    {
        private static int res_health;
        private static int res_wood;
        private static int res_gold;
        private static int res_steel;

```
    private static int stat_str;
    private static int stat_int;
    private static int stat_wit;
    private static int stat_maxHp;
    private static int stat_otvaga;

    private static final String queryLoad = "SELECT * FROM resc";

    private TextView txtHealth;

     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);


     }
     @Override
     public void onPause()
     {
      super.onPause();
     }

     @Override 
     public void onResume()
     {
         super.onResume();
     }

     public  Game()
     {

     TextView textHealth = new TextView(this);
     textHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.strHealth);

     res_health = 25;
     res_wood = 0;
     res_gold = 0;
     res_steel = 0;

     stat_str = 4;
     stat_int = 3;
     stat_wit = 3;
     stat_maxHp = 25;
     stat_otvaga = 0;
     textHealth.setText(res_health);// TODO:ОШИБКА!
     }
```

The error is that it asks for Force Close only when i use the TextView

Comment: please remove this TextView textHealth = new TextView(this); and check it agian . it works .

Comment: let me show your error log in logcat

Answer (score 3):

Please remove below line.

TextView textHealth = new TextView(this);

and for setting text

textHealth.setText(""+res_health);

use public void game() instead of public game()

see the complete answer

```
 private static int stat_str;
    private static int stat_int;
    private static int stat_wit;
    private static int stat_maxHp;
    private static int stat_otvaga;

    private static final String queryLoad = "SELECT * FROM resc";

    private TextView txtHealth;

     @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);


     }
     @Override
     public void onPause()
     {
      super.onPause();
     }

     @Override 
     public void onResume()
     {
         super.onResume();
     }

     public void Game()
     {

    // TextView textHealth = new TextView(this);
     txtHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.strHealth);

     res_health = 25;
     res_wood = 0;
     res_gold = 0;
     res_steel = 0;

     stat_str = 4;
     stat_int = 3;
     stat_wit = 3;
     stat_maxHp = 25;
     stat_otvaga = 0;
     txtHealth.setText(""+res_health);// TODO:ОШИБКА!
     }
```

Comment: what you see in your logcat?can you show your game.xml layout file?

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the fact you are using `TextView.setText(int)` which is not what you want to do. The int you provide is what you want to display, but Android thinks that this is a resource ID (cf : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29).

Try to use `textHealth.setText(String.valueOf(res_health));` instead.

Comment: u see even when i write this textHealth.setText(11); error comes

Comment: @cr3a70r:This is of course an error.what you expect from an error rather than error?setText expect parameter as a string.not something like 11

Comment: textHealth.setText(String.valueOf("11")); that too

Comment: if you use "11" then there is no need to use String.valueOf

Comment: then clik window->show View-> if you don't find logcat then click other.you will find logcat there

Comment: hahahah Java Forever!!! when i pressed the logcat i got crash of my opera + adb and after restarting eclipse im getting an [2011-06-27 15:08:45 - AndroStrategy] Failed to install AndroStrategy.apk on device 'HT08TL900721': timeout
[2011-06-27 15:08:45 - AndroStrategy] Launch canceled!

Comment: also assure in your game.xml the text view id is set like   android:id="@+id/strHealth"

Comment: im already tired of java errors, eclipse stacks, eclipse crashes... this java must die as soon as possible. the future is still C/C++ and Assembler.

Comment: check the name of your textview

Comment: <TextView android:id="@+id/strHealth" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/gres_n_hp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: its okay.now in your activity.txtHealth and textHealth.

Comment: TextView  textHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.strHealth);

Comment: So why you wrote private TextView txtHealth; change this to textHealth

Comment: u know what?.. the error fears out when i comment this line txtHealth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.strHealth);

Comment: assure in every place it is txtHealth.Not textHealth

Comment: my general question? or where ?

Comment: i copied the code in my general question and i still get this error

Comment: use public void game() istead of public game()

Comment: am.. game() is a CONSTRUCTOR and Constructors NEVER return a value.

Comment: hm.Your class Name was not present

Answer (score 1):

try

```
textHealth.setText(""+res_health)
```

in your example it consider it as the int val of R.java file  so dats y its through the exception

Answer (score 1):

You mixed 'textHealth' and 'txtHealth'.

Comment: there is no mix. im not using a class variable. im using the local-in-function variable